# Carrying A Variable Over To An Iframe

Tags: php, variables, iframe

I'm trying to make a timer in php.  It is on a iframe so that the iframe can refresh regularly.  I'm having trouble carrying the session variable over to the iframe.  If i echo the session variable on the page (above the iframe) it display's correct but it does not want to echo in the iframe.  Please help.

**page1**

```
<?php
session_start();
....
if ($_SESSION['auth']) {
$d=getdate();
$h=$d['hours'];
$m=$d['minutes'];
$s=$d['seconds'];
$_SESSION['h']=$h;
$_SESSION['m']=$m;
$_SESSION['s']=$s;
$_SESSION['m12']=-1;
echo "<a href='http://localhost/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=50&tid=$tid'>Continue</a>";
?>
```

**page2**

```
<IFRAME SRC="timer.php" WIDTH=450 HEIGHT=100></IFRAME>
```

**timer.php**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; ">
<?php
session_start();
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$hourin=$_SESSION['h'];
$minin=$_SESSION['m'];
$secin=$_SESSION['s'];
echo $secin . " ";
```

Comment: This might not directly fix your problem, but what you are (or seem to be) trying to do is achieved much more easily (and better) with Javascript. You don't need an additional PHP file or sessions to make a timer.

Comment: +1 Kokos, this can easily be done much prettier and better with js.

Answer (score 0):

In `timer.php`, move `session_start()` to the first line of the script. Sessions require cookies, which are set in headers, which cannot be modified after content is sent unless you have output buffering enabled.

This may not fix the problem, but please do it anyway as it will avoid other problems you may run into later.

If this does not fix the problem, please show us the result of `var_dump($_SESSION);` when called both at the end of `page1`, and in the body of `timer.php`.

Comment: I've changed it to the following in timer.php but still no luck:
`<head>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; ">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$secin=$_SESSION['s'];
echo $secin;
?>
</body>`

I'll try the var_dump and report back

Comment: No, it needs to be the *first line* in the script. So it should be `<?php session_start(); ?><head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; "> </head>...`

Comment: the vardump gives the following:  
**page1**
["s"]=> int(49)

**timer.php**
array(0) { }

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've changed it to the very first line but still not working.  Sigh.  I don't understand, it should work, I mean it's stored in the session.

Comment: I think you probably need to [read up on](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)/check your session cookie parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you pass the variable in the iframe url as a get value it might solve your problem. Example, in page 2 create the iframe link as:

```
<IFRAME SRC="timer.php?h=<?php echo $h; ?>&m=<?php echo $m; ?>&s=<?php echo $s; ?>" WIDTH=450 HEIGHT=100></IFRAME>
```

and in timer.php

```
<?php
$hour = $_GET['h'];
$min = $_GET['m'];
$sec = $_GET['s'];
...
?>
```

Comment: I've tried that but it does not work, I can see the value of sec in my url but still it does not want to echo it in timer.php:
`http://localhost/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=50&tid=13&s=53`
and then in timer.php:  
`<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; ">
<?php
session_start();
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$sec = $_GET['s'];
echo $sec;
?>
</body>`